# how to compile webobject apache adaptor?

Tags: webobjects, adaptor

i followed the instruction of below link.

http://www.rdbprime.com/Documentation/WebObjects/Deployment/Deploying_Applications/Installation/Building_the_Adaptors.html

But I'm getting the following error when I am compiling Apache Adaptor.

```
c: not found  
make[1]: [mod_WebObjects.so] Error 2 (ignored)  
strip  mod_WebObjects.so  
strip: not found  
make[1]: *** [mod_WebObjects.so] Error 2  
make: *** [Apache] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you provided is very old, are you sure you wan't to build such an old adapter? WebObjects has moved to Java a long time ago and the Adapter has changed a lot since then.

For example you can find current information about compiling it for Linux here:

http://wiki.wocommunity.org/display/documentation/Compiling+the+HTTP+adaptor+on+Linux